# How can I automatically accept Artifactory EULA?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I have been using Artifactory OSS and set it up with a deploy script. The deploy script also uploads some images with curl to a generic repo immediately after setup. Now I need to upload docker images as well so I made the switch to Artifactory JCR. JCR won't accept my curl push until I have accepted the EULA. Is it possible to accept it automatically? I have been looking for a EULA flag in files and the database but without success.

My environment is a docker container with artifactory-jcr:6.17.0 in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For deployments using a scripts, you can sign the JCR EULA in a YAML configuration file you have prepared ahead. As JCR is based on Artifactory, the configuration files are usually similar.

Create a YAML file at `$JCR_HOME/etc/artifactory/artifactory.config.import.yml`

Add the below

```
GeneralConfiguration: 
  eula: 
    accepted: true
    
OnboardingConfiguration:
  repoTypes:
    - docker
    - helm
```

Make sure to format it as YAML before writing to the file

Comment: I found out that the EULA flag is set in a file called artifactory.config.xml. This file is stored in binary form in the database table artifactory.configs. I'm glad there was another preferred way to do it than injecting the flag in the db.

Answer (score 9):

One more option is to use this curl in the script, after JFrog Container Registry is installed:

```
curl -XPOST -vu username:password http://${ArtifactoryURL}/artifactory/ui/jcr/eula/accept
```